# Error correction with asymmetric channel

Tags: coding-theory

Suppose A is trying to transmit a message to B over a noisy low bandwidth channel, while B has the ability to simultaneously transmit arbitrary amounts of information losslessly to A. Are there particular encoding algorithms adapted to this scenario? It seems like the ability to provide feedback to A should allow for faster information transmission. I've tried searching for this, but I haven't found anything, partly because I don't even know what terms to search for.

Comment: (1) Two papers you might want to look at are "List Decoding with Side Information" by Guruswami and "On interactive communication" by Ahlswede, Cai and Zhang. They do not consider your model, though, but possibly they contain interesting ideas. (2) I believe that (in a deterministic setting) the best thing B can do is to send the received message (including the noise) back to A. But that is only my intuition and might be wrong.